# wrong (Please fill out this field ) message in html

Tags: html, forms, required

I have several separated forms in my HTML page and each form has a several `required inputs`

when I fill all inpus in the first form and I want to submit the first form the page alarm me `Please fill out this field` in second forms inpust,  although I just want to submit  the first form ,and I don't want to fill  the second form ! 
 this is a simple example :
if you want to just fill the first form and you want to submit `send1` , page alarm you you must fill the second form inputs too !

```
<form action='' method='POST'>
            title1 : <input name='title1'  type='text' required  > <br>
            content1 : <input name='content1'  type='text' required  ><br>
            <input name='send1' type='submit'  value='send1' >
<form>  
<br>
<form action='' method='POST'>
            title2: <input name='title2'  type='text' required  > <br>
            content2 : <input name='content2 '  type='text' required  ><br>
            <input name='send2' type='submit'  value='send2' >
<form>
```

this is  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soheilyou/r1vad5pf/)

for solving this issue the first idea  was that I use jQuery but I think there  are some other simple ways 
jquery :

```
$("otherinputs").prop('required', false);
```

I dont want to use jquery

Comment: Why you dont complete form with `</form>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

close your form tags `<form></form>` to solve the problems:

```
<form action='' method='POST'>
            title1 : <input name='title1'  type='text' required  > <br>
            content1 : <input name='content1'  type='text' required  ><br>
            <input name='send1' type='submit'  value='send1' >
</form>  
<br>
<form action='' method='POST'>
            title2: <input name='title2'  type='text' required  > <br>
            content2 : <input name='content2 '  type='text' required  ><br>
            <input name='send2' type='submit'  value='send2' >
</form>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/afshin2740/r1vad5pf/1/)

Comment: oh my god I was searching for a complicated problem  but there was a simple mistake ,thank you guys مرسی داداش ;)